# ¿porque se duplican los Links de React en un componente?

Tags: reactjs, component

estoy iniciándome en React y hay comportamientos del renderizado que me falta comprender por mas que haya leído parte de la documentación, se que la información viaja en dos sentidos para distribuirla en todos los componente y hasta ahí llega mi entendimiento, pues he armado varios componentes para crear una lista de categorías de productos en un componente ItemListContainer con Link cada uno para mostrar las listas de sus productos respectivamente, y a su vez cada producto individual tiene otro Link para ver los detalles del mismo en otros componentes, ItemDetailContainer e ItemDetail, en estos detalles ni hay una suerte de duplicación tal vez porque tiene otra lógica de renderizado.

Entonces me creo poder centrarme en el componente ItemListContainer que aparentemente renderiza dos veces la lista de Links, aclaro que esta lista de Link está dentro de un fragment y no en un , que tampoco provienen estos Links de una iteración, si hay una iteración de la data que proviene de un useState (variable "categories") actualizado por un useEffect al cambiar la url con los Links, y acá si hay iteraciones para cada la categoría que corresponda y renderiza solo esos productos en un componente ItemList.

Este comportamiento sucede cuando estas en la ruta raiz y en la ruta de categorías, "/" y "/category/:categoryId"

Por otro lado ya intenté de simplificar componentes eliminando componente App que anida en el padre de todos que es Index y sucede lo mismo.

Las rutas aparecen bien configuradas he hice pruebas eliminando algunos componentes de las rutas e igual continúa el fallo.

COMPONENTE ItemListContainer.jsx   (tal vez el que tenga la falla)

```
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import { arrayplano } from '../../helpers/arrayplano';
import { ItemList } from '../ItemList';
import { useParams , Link } from "react-router-dom";

//Este componente agrupa las 7 categorías. Componente PADRE
export const ItemListContainer = (props)=>{

      //pasar un array vacío funcionó en useState, ya que si pasamos un objeto utiliza eso, sino espera un array de dependencias
    
    const {categoryId} = useParams();

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    const promesa = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve(arrayplano);
    })

    useEffect(()=>{
        promesa.then(resultado=>{            
            if(!categoryId){                
                setCategories(resultado)
            } else{
                // console.log(resultado)
                const nuevaLista = resultado.filter(item=>item.categ === categoryId);
                setCategories(nuevaLista)
                console.log(nuevaLista)
            }
        })
    },[categoryId])

    return(
        <div className="item-list-container">
            <h2 style={props.style}>{props.greeting}</h2>
            {console.log(categoryId)}
            
            <Link to={'/category/harinas'}>HARINAS DE MAIZ Y VARIOS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="harinas"? categories.map((category)=>{
                    //la key unicamente la puedo establecer donde etá el .map() no dentro del componente ItemList
                    return ( 
                        <li key={category.id}>  
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/frutas'}>FRUTAS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="frutas"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (                            
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>                        
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/quesos'}>QUESOS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="quesos"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/salsas_y_cremas'}>SALSAS Y CREMAS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="salsas_y_cremas"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/bebidas'}>BEBIDAS Y MÁS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="bebidas"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/golosinas'}>GOLOSINAS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="golosinas"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>

            <Link to={'/category/varios'}>VARIOS</Link>
            <ul>
                {categoryId==="varios"?categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={category.id}>
                            <ItemList productsList={category}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }):""}
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
};
```

Componente de rutas

```
import { Routes , Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AboutUs} from "../components/views/AboutUs";
import { ProductsList } from "../components/views/ProductList";
import { Stores } from "../components/views/Stores";
import { ToBuy } from "../components/views/ToBuy";
import { Error404 } from "../components/views/Error404";
import { ItemListContainer } from "../components/ItemListContainer";
import { ItemDetailContainer } from "../components/ItemDetailContainer";

export const RouterApp = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/aboutus"              element={<AboutUs />}></Route>
                <Route path="/"                     element={<ItemListContainer />}></Route>
                <Route path="/category/:categoryId" element={<ItemListContainer />}></Route>
                <Route path="/item/:productId"      element={<ItemDetailContainer />}></Route>
                <Route path="/productslist"         element={<ProductsList/>}></Route>
                <Route path="/stores"               element={<Stores />}></Route>
                <Route path="/tobuy"                element={<ToBuy />}></Route>
                <Route path="*"                     element={<Error404 />}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
};
```

Componente App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import { ItemListContainer } from './components/ItemListContainer';
import { RouterApp } from './router/RouterApp';

const h2Style= {
  color: 'orange',
  background: 'green',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: '18px'
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>      
      <NavBar/>
      <ItemListContainer style={h2Style} greeting={"Hola!!! buenos días!! Bienvenido a nuestro E-Comosano!!"}/>
      <RouterApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Componente Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Estos son los errores en el Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya agradezco sus ayudas y dejo el repositorio por si se necesita, el proyecto ejercicio está en base a React js con npx create-react- app.
Saludos!!

[REPOSITORIO GIT HUB DE EJERCICIO](https://github.com/PADAGUDEV/react-preentrega2-guzman.git)

Comment: Te aparecen 2 veces porque uno lo renderizas en el app.js y otro dentro del router, con el path = "/". Tienes que eliminar el que renderizas en el app.js

Comment: Excelente tu aporte, vi cuál es mi error la forma de pensar los renderizados que son redundantes al agregar routes debo de dejar de usar los componentes a renderizar tradicionalmente sin routes, o uso rutas o uso componentes individuales o anidados, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que en el App estás llamando al componente ItemListContainer, cuando llama a dicho componente luego entra a RouterApp y vuelve a llamar ItemListContainer, para resolver esto tendrías que sacar ItemListContainer de la App

PD: Otra sugerencia de código, en App tenés el componente NavBar, este lo sacaría de allí, lo que haría es poner un folder Layout dentro de tus views y que dentro esté el componente NavBar y los children que llegan por parámetro, luego en RouterApp llamas a Layout y este tiene que ser padre de , te dejo un ejemplo de código:

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <NavBar />
      {children}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
<Layout>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs />}></Route>
 </Routes>
</Layout>
```

Comment: Excelente Alan, entonces necesito cambiar mi forma de pensar sobre el renderizado a usar rutas que contengan los componentes y dejar de usar los componentes solos o anidados fuera de rutas hasta el index.js que nuclea toda la app. Evidentemente arrastré la costumbre básica sin usar rutas mezclada con rutas. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Y por el agregado de tu aporte sobre aplicar un folder Layout es excelente, gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación a ayudarme, gracias!